# body padding in single page angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to give the padding to body of template in angular ng-app?

Where should I put css for ng-app rendered templete?
please see this fiddle for example

https://jsfiddle.net/aghsqnpa/

```
div.ngview {
    padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
}
```

**Disclaimer :** I don't have any experience in CSS.

Comment: not able to understand...what you want exactly

Comment: _“I don't have any experience in CSS”_ – well that’s the thing you need to change then. Start with basics like what’s the difference between an id and a class, and how selecting elements by each of those works in CSS.

Comment: There will be two Scope for css to go. One on app level and one on template level. That is what I understood. Please see answers if you didn't get me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create un custom css file that you will call after the default css file used by your project (if that is the case). 
For your example : you can set css properties on an id element by declaring it like this :

```
#ngview {
    padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
}
```

Comment: Just remember that to set css on a class you need to call it with a point : .yourClass and to set css on an id you will use #yourId

Comment: This is what I wanted.

Comment: Good ! As suggested above, try to learn the basics of css, its really not too hard and you will be able to design your templates as you wish ! If my answer is fine please mark it as accepted :D

Comment: By the way, if you actually want to center your div, you should try to use margin instead of padding, (like margin: 0 auto). It will center your div depending of the parent's div. And please 'mark my answer as accepted'!! it helps aha

Answer (score 1):

Put this css code on the css part of the jsfiddle to understand what section you can target.

```css
// whole page
body {
  background: red;
}

// router links
.container {
  background: green;  
}

// router view
#ngview {
  background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have this code in your html:

```
 <style>
    .container {
      text-align: center;
      padding:50px;
    }
.dropdownmenu ul,
.dropdownmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdownmenu ul {
  background: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdownmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}

.dropdownmenu a {
  background: #30A6E6;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
  background: #000000;
}
```

Just add the padding in yout `.container` class and it will work.

I strongly reccomend to create a separate syle.css file and import it from your index page tho.

https://jsfiddle.net/aghsqnpa/1/